# Force @GrailsCompileStatic check request as AbstractMultipartHttpServletRequest

Tags: grails, groovy, multipart, static-compilation

I'm trying to apply `@GrailsCompileStatic` to controller that has an action that retrieves MultipartFiles from request:

```
request.getFile('foo')
```

But get the following:

> [Static type checking] - Cannot find matching method
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest#getFile(java.lang.String)

Is there any chance to force compiler to verify request against `AbstractMultipartHttpServletRequest` (that has the getFile(java.lang.String) method) instead of `HttpServletRequest`?

**UPD**
This solution works:

```
MultipartFile multipartFile = ((StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest) request).getFile('myFile')
```

But has some strange behaviour when trying to test it:

> org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot
>   cast object
>   'org.grails.plugins.testing.GrailsMockHttpServletRequest@2bcf856f'
>   with class 'org.grails.plugins.testing.GrailsMockHttpServletRequest'
>   to class
>   'org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://docs.grails.org/2.2.1/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/plugins/testing/GrailsMockHttpServletRequest.html

and

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/support/StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.html

both implements an interface

[org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartHttpServletRequest](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/MultipartHttpServletRequest.html)

so just use this

```
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartHttpServletRequest
...

MultipartFile multipartFile = ((MultipartHttpServletRequest) request).getFile('myFile')
```